# How to color a plot with ggplot2 according to 2 variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I want to plot change in weight over time for 9 different groups and I have colored the plot adding `color=Group` in ggplot.
Now I have another column with information about which box was each animal located in(no of boxes=3) and I want to add this information to the plot too.
Ideally, I would like to  see the lines colored by different shades of 3 colors. How can I do this in R?

```
bcs_avg <- read_excel("C:/BCS1.xlsx",sheet = 2,col_names = TRUE)

pl <- ggplot(bcs_avg,aes(x=Month, y=Average,color=factor(Group)))+
geom_line()
```

Comment: It would be helpfull if you could make your example reproducible by including a small subset of your data.
Aside from that it is not generally possible to use two color schemes at the same time. You could however use another aesthetic such as lintetype or the alpha channel. 
If you want to use only colors you can add a column in your original data indicating to which color group it should belong and then use this for color instead of the group you are using now. Or look at `interaction(Group, Box)` for the color (adapted to your column names).

Comment: I have tried to use different line types, but I get an error: not possible to use linetype command with continuos data.

Comment: If you add some example data it will be much easier to help you. See here for options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I guess you encoded your box variable as a number. You need to do aes(x=Month, y=Average,color=factor(Group),linetype=factor(Box))